# A virtual folder/index of folders in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

I have a folder with lots of folders inside, each of these folders have some folders which finally have files in them. See example below (the number of folders, subfolders in folders or files in subfolders is not determined here).

```
folder1
- subfolder1
  - file1
- subfolder2
  - file2
folder2
- subfolder1
  - file3
- subfolder2
  - file4
```

Notice that subfolder names are the same! I would like to (without editing the above folder structure at all) access them using a different folder structure, for example:

```
subfolder1
- folder1
  - file1
- folder2
  - file3
subfolder2
- folder1
  - file2
- folder2
  - file4
```

or just:

```
subfolder1
- file1
- file3
subfolder2
- file2
- file4
```

I have absolutely no clue how to go about this (or even what to search as the title might suggest). Any help would be welcome.

Comment: You can write a program to do it.  Or you could use symlinks but thats a lot of work.  How many folders and is the structure static or dynamic

Comment: @RohitGupta there's around 100 folders with 900 subfolders and 50000 files in total. The structure is somewhat static in that it rarely changes, but can change occasionally.

Comment: I can only symbolic links as a solution.  Where you remap folders (and/or files) into a different location.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach your second example view using **Exporer**'s search:

With this sample structure:

```
PS Altenate Folder Tree> tree .\ /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 000000C7 F057:590D
C:\USERS\KEITH\SANDBOX\ALTENATE FOLDER TREE
├───Folder1
│   ├───SubFolder1
│   │       File1
│   │
│   └───SubFolder2
│           File2
│
└───Folder2
    ├───SubFolder1
    │       FIle3
    │
    └───SubFolder2
            File4
```

In **Explorer**, from your top-level folder, click in the search box and type `kind:NOT Folder`:

[image]

Then, in your `Search Resuts in...` window, add the `Folder Name` Column:

[image]

Then, from the `View` ribbon or the background context menu: `Group by` -> `Folder Name`:

[image]

If you opt to use the `Save Serach` feature, it will un-group when you save becasue **Explorer** is now displaying your "new" saved search (check the Address Bar) in the default view. But if you group that and then close the window, it will have retained the grouped view when re-opened.